# Issues with building matplotlib-cpp

Tags: c++, cmake

I downloaded the matplotlib-cpp And I created a CMakeList.txt to build it. Contents of CmakeList.txt

```
project(myproject)
find_package(Python2 COMPONENTS Development NumPy)
target_include_directories(myproject PRIVATE ${Python2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Python2_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(myproject Python2::Python Python2::NumPy)
```

But as soon as I hit command `cmake ../` I get this error

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Python2: /usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (found version "2.7.17") found components: Development NumPy Interpreter 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (target_include_directories):
  Cannot specify include directories for target "myproject" which is not
  built by this project.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "myproject" which is not built by
  this project.


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/heisenbug/myproject/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Can I get some help regarding this issue, I think the issue lies in the name `myproject`

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: First you need a target `myproject`. Then you should add `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)`. You should read the error messages.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you trying to build [this](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp) repo? It looks like it already comes with a Makefile, so you can just run `make`. Or are you trying to include this repo in your *own* CMake-based project? If that is the case, you don't mention any of your *own* code in the CMake file...

Comment: Just using `make` did the thing, ty for your help